# Importing styles in multiple components on React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript with React on Rails.

My SCSS file is in same folder with tsx files and this scss file import all necessary modules. So i have a one big css file at the end.

I also have 42 components. Every component has a html code that renders. So, I import styles in components like this:

```
import * as styles from 'main.module.scss';
```

Problem is, my page loads fast. But styles are delayed a bit. At first i see html dom object without styles then styles applied. This wonders me that, **does React loads my scss styles 42 times** or just once and re-use on each components?

If not how can i globally import `styles` and use across all components?

**sample component**

```
import * as styles from 'main.module.scss';

...

render() {

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>

       <div className={styles.pageInner}>
          content...
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you just need to import the global style in the top level js file, for example `app.js`, only for the module css you need load it every time in each component.

Comment: TypeScript is strict so when i import at top level, child components cant see styles variable. I needed to import all the time

Comment: can you paste some code which show how you use the style in the component? I guess you mix the global css and module css.

Comment: added a sample usage

Comment: btw it is a `main.module.scss` and i export styles with typing extension

Answer (score 1):

> does React loads my scss styles 42 times

I just did the experiment, the answer is no. although this, it is still not recommended to put all styles in a file. I think you should separate your `main.module.scss` to many small files.

there are 2 kinds of CSS style.

one is a global style which shared by multiple components, for example, you define it in `global.scss` file, this file is just needed to import once at the top level js file.

```
// global.scss
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

// applicaiton.js
import "global.scss"

// ExampleComponent.jsx, don't need to import "global.scss"
// className should be the string
...
render() {
  return <div className='container'>example</div>
}
```

another one is a module style which is only used by a component or a very few components, and it should just include the styles only used in the target component, it is usually small and has the same name as the component.

```
// ExampleComponent.module.scss
.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

 // ExampleComponent.jsx
import * as styles from 'ExampleComponent.module.scss'

...
render() {
  return <div className={styles.container}>Example</div>
}
```

if you want to mix the global style and module style in the same element, you can use `classnames` npm or like this:

```
 // ExampleComponent.jsx
import * as styles from 'ExampleComponent.module.scss'

...
render() {
  return <div className={`container ${styles.container}`}>Example</div>
}
```

Comment: gotcha. I was using modules because 1) It obfuscate/shorten class names. (helpful for size+load time) 2) I generate typings so that `styles.classN` <= autocompletes in VSCode. Is there a way to import global.scss globally and use like `styles.container` in all components so my IDE knows it is

Comment: as my understanding, nope.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webpacker or a similar gem to manage this? Webpack is smart enough to reuse imports - it won't include it a ton of times.

That said, since CSS is global, you only need to import `main.scss` once anyway, at the top level.

Comment: yes, im using webpacker. TypeScript is strict so when i import at top level, child components cant see styles variable. I needed to import all the time.

Comment: what do you mean "typescript is so strict"? How are you writing your code (TS should not have any knowledge about sass variables).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using webpack, one option would be to compile Scss to plain CSS and include it as a stylesheet in the root HTML page, most likely, index.html